# dolphin-emu no longer works on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, dolphin

On Ubuntu 21.10, dolphin-emu was accessible via a simple `sudo apt install dolphin-emu`. I didn't need to add a ppa or anything like that, despite Dolphin's official instructions. I suspect this is probably because it was available via Debian. *edit it was available in Ubuntu 21.10 Universe repo, and not in Debian main*

This no longer works in Ubuntu 22.04, and my existing dolphin-emu was removed when I upgraded. When I try to install it I'm met with this message.

```
Package dolphin-emu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

So clearly it was here, but the upgrade to 22.04 from 21.10 removed the binary from my system. The PPA also fails with this error

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So how is one expected to install dolphin-emu on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: It looks like it's not in Ubuntu repos after 21.10 and the PPA also hasn't been updated for 22.04. I suggest that you contact the developers of the project. Perhaps they are behind on development or the project has been discontinued (in total or for Linux)

Comment: Looks like dolphin-emu is not apart of Debian 11 main, and was in the Universe (community-maintained) packages in Ubuntu 21.10.

Guess I should either bark up Dolphin's tree, figure out how to add it to Ubuntu's repositories, or make due with a version I build locally. I'd prefer to have it added to Ubuntu's repositories. Do you know how to go about doing that?

Comment: Most packages in Ubuntu come upstream from Debian, so if Debian didn't include it, then Ubuntu probably won't either. I would reach out to the folks who dev/maintain the package. They should be aware of the status of their software as it pertains to the inclusion in Debian and Ubuntu. Since they presumably know why it's not included anymore, they are also the best people to ask how to get it included again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Not really because my question is "How do I install dolphin-emu on Ubuntu 22.04" and that question says "Use an updated release file", but AFAIK none exists for dolphin-emu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snap version works just fine on 22.04.

`sudo snap install dolphin-emulator`

Refer to this site for full installation instructions:
https://snapcraft.io/install/dolphin-emulator/ubuntu#install

Comment: I'll have to accept that because that's what I've been using as of late. 1% inconvenient for me since having as much as possible under apt is nice, but dolphin is one of the best projects out there so I'll take what they offer

Answer (score 2):

I just installed it fine on Ubuntu 22.04 following the "Building Dolphin on Linux" guide on wiki-dolphin-emu. It takes a while to build and install but it does seem to work for The Wind Waker so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin Emulator is also available on [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu)

Intall
`https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu`

Download
`flatpak run org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu`

Comment: That's probably better than the snap tbh, since snaps can't read from my usual external mount points (for some retarded reason), and perhaps a flatpak can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to upvote captainkout and comment his answer, but some brainiac figured it was a good idea to lock upvotes behind "reputation system".

Anyway, Flatpak worked for me and you don't need that answer's link to install. You may install using:

`flatpak install org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu`

then the run line just like his answer stated:

`flatpak run org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu`

If this is unnecessary to you now, I hope it is useful to the next Linux gamer that stumbles upon dolphin-emu's ban from apt repos.

Comment: Oh man, shitting on SO. I like you already

Comment: Why the SO? Just the forum. It was an adventure running the SO so far, but I like most of how he was made and planned